# Why is this code not terminating and going on for infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, graph, deque

This is my attempt at solving Leetcode's Question no [841](https://leetcode.com/problems/keys-and-rooms/)
What I have done is, I made an array dp which has the size of `len(rooms)` and all are intially 0. Then I set dp[0] to be 1.
The I made dequeu called `queue` and appended the first room that he can go. From there which ever room keys he has he goes there marking dp[k]=1 and once when all possible ways are over the queue should be empty and I should end up with the ans.

But when I run this code it showed me TLE error hence I added the print statements to debug and then the output is something that is beyond my understanding. I know I can get solutions in discuss section but I want to what I have done wrong here.

Here is the code:-

```
class Solution:
    def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        n=len(rooms)
        dp=[0]*n
        dp[0]=1
        print(dp)
        queue=deque()
        queue.append(rooms[0])
        while queue:
            print(queue)
            i=queue.popleft()
            for k in i:
                dp[k]=1
                queue.append(rooms[k])
        if 0 in dp:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: You're not checking where you've been.  Once you visited room 2, you never need to visit there again.  Picture `[[2],[3],[0],[1]]`.  You would loop forever between room 0 and room 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God! The problem that was happening here was that when ever I encourtered a room I was appending it to the queue so, that room took me to some other room and like that this kept on going hence the infinite loop.

Just 1 small correction and it worked
Here is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def canVisitAllRooms(self, rooms: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        n=len(rooms)
        dp=[0]*n
        dp[0]=1
        # print(dp)
        queue=deque()
        queue.append(rooms[0])
        while queue:
            # print(queue)
            i=queue.popleft()
            for k in i:
                if not dp[k]:
                    dp[k]=1
                    queue.append(rooms[k])
        if 0 in dp:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because inside while loop you are keep on increasing queue by code used `queue.append(rooms[k])`
so in every loop when it goes to `while queue:` it will have the new element you appended (rooms[k]).
You can put some condition to before appending queue or some exit condition from the loop.